# Screenshot sizes for publishing on Google Play not working

Tags: android, google-play, screenshot

I'm publishing my application on Google Play, and my screenshots are 800x1627. It's higher than the min, and lower than the max.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to resize your screenshot. Constraints:

- Min length for any side: 320px.
- Max length for any side: 3840px.
- Max aspect ratio: 2:1.

In your case, the aspect ratio is not correct. If you want to maintain the width of 800px, then the maximum height can only be 1600px (or a minimum of 400px).

Comment: How can I modify the aspect ratio?

Comment: You have to modify the width or height pixels, in order to modify the aspect ratio.

Comment: I had to change the aspect ratio of the image to 16:9. Removed the upper status bar and the bottom navigation bar.

Comment: Yeah basically they are just telling you to remove the status bar and footer that is not part of your app.

Comment: it seem the Height must NO more than 2x of width

Comment: @DroidChris source on this? I've always found it strange that screenshots from Google's own emulated devices weren't accepted on their own store. This seems like a valid reason. I didn't get the memo.

Comment: I just take the emulated screen shots and remove the status bar and footer and the aspect ratio is then good.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky - modify the aspect ratio of the canvas not the image itself. The Play Store has to cope with aspect ratios of phones, WearOS TVs and tablets

Answer (score 14):

Just as mentioned in the 1st answer your resolution should be in a ratio of "**2:1**" So I was using Samsung galaxy S9 screenshots that had a resolution of *1080x2220* So to make it *2:1* I just went to an online image resizer like [this](https://resizeimage.net/)
and resized the image to **1080x2160** where it doesn't exceed the 3840px max limit either, and the image upload was a success.

Hope the answer helps :)

Answer (score 6):

---

it means to change your height and width of your image. aspect ratio **2:1** means two times height more than width. if your width is 800 then your height should be 1600. 
for example in Photoshop you can do it with change the size of image in image menu/image size.

Answer (score 5):

I encounter this problem every time I take screenshots from my phone, I resolved it by modifying the image resolution, to be specific by **minimizing** the height image. From 1080x**2220** to 1080x**2160**.

Clear explanation:

**2:1** aspect ratio is twice as wide as it is tall. This is why you need to resize your screenshot,.

I calculated the good resolution via this [website](https://calculateaspectratio.com/):
Just put your image width in 'Pixel Width' input and the height will be automatically calculated :)

[image]

### More explanation about Dimensions and aspect ratios:

[So, let’s say you have an image measuring 1920 pixels in width by 1080 pixels in height (that size equates to a Full HD image), and you had to crop it to fit a 2:1 space: you could simply leave the width intact, and crop the height down to exactly half, at 960 pixels.](https://thenextweb.com/basics/2019/02/12/how-to-crop-your-images-to-a-specific-size-or-aspect-ratio/)

Answer (score 5):

The 1080x2160 size worked for me. I used the Pixlr online image editor to change the ***canvas*** size of the screenshot. The Play Store has screenshots for phone, tablet, TV and Wear OS which can be different sizes and aspect ratios.

[pixlr](https://pixlr.com/editor/)

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who is looking for an "out of the box" solution, the Google Pixel 2XL emulator will provide you with an aspect ratio size of 2:1 for which you can take screeenshots with.

Comment: I've been looking for an answer to this simple question: which Android Emulator will give you screenshots accepted to Google Play. I've found it frustrating that my Pixel 3a emulator screenshots won't be accepted on Google's own developer console!

Answer (score 0):

For Microsoft Xamarin development on Windows 10 I created the various images using this approach:
1) Paint 3D for setting a rectangle of the right pixel size (see the canvas part).
2) Copy the rectangle from Step 1 to Powerpoint. Add, size graphics.
3) Copy graphic from 2) into Paint 3D and resize to exact pixels. Save image.
4) Import image to Google playstore

Yes, I know it is a hassle.

All the best
Stew

Answer (score -4):

The fastest and easiest way to do this is to take a screenshot from Android Studio itself while your device is connected and running the application.
After that save the picture and you can add it to the Store listing straight away.
[image]

Comment: I doesn't fit aspect ratio for Google Play console